# How to add the option to manually mark a customer review as "Verified owner" at woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, review

I receive some reviews of my products from external marketplaces and I usually add them manually at my own shop (with a link to the source).

How can I mark those reviews as "Verified owner" (as they really are). I´m currently adding it via Database but I´m pretty sure it is possible to make it via Admin Dashboard.

Comment: **Verified owner** depends on the comment's author email and user ID which WooCommerce uses to find if a customer with that email and ID bought that product or not, if yes then WooCommerce will save the `verified` comment meta as `1`, I am unsure if you can change the **comment_author_email** and **user_id** from admin dashboard or not.

Comment: You can edit that value (the comment meta as verified just adding the number 1) via database, I suppose it is possible to edit this value via admin dashboard.